# TFS: only SOME tests are discovered in the same assembly

Tags: tfs, vstest

Using the very latest TFS 2017 release 2 (about to upgrade to 3 by the look of it), on-prem.  Tests are MSTest.  I recently consolidated all our tests into one assembly, which are usually distributed to 6 VMs to process in parallel (have been using only 2 lately for unrelated reasons, a problem which I am currently engaged with MS in solving).  The tests not being discovered are not included in the total that shows in the log/console during the Run Functional Tests step of the build.  It should be ~1400 total tests, but it shows only 896.  As far as I can tell, the tests not being properly discovered are the ones that were in the assemblies that got consolidated out of existence.  My method of consolidating was basically to move the code files (.cs) from those assemblies to the single assembly we have now and adjust the namespaces so that all the tests are in the same namespace.  No other code changes.

So how can it find only some tests, when all have appropriate attributes (the build definition is set to run only tests with a category of "Automated", which all of these tests have) and all in fact are in the very same namespace?  I am at a loss.

Comment: Are the tests all using the same test framework? You're sure that the assembly is being built and the location you're pointing to contains the just-built test assembly? Did you try building with "clean" set to make sure everything is getting freshly synched up?

Comment: Yes, everything is building fine, as is evidenced by the fact that SOME of the tests within the assembly are in fact being discovered and run as expected.  Our build automatically deletes all traces of the previous build, so it is forced to build every time in a "clean" environment from scratch.  Also of note:  All the tests are discovered correctly and can be run with success in the Test Explorer window.  It is only on the build server that the problem presents itself.

Comment: @Dan Did you set the `Test Filter criteria` for the  `Run Functional Tests` step? A filter to specify the tests to execute within the test assembly files.